# How to send FCM Notification to a list of specific device tokens using the v1 API

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to use the new FCM HTTP v1 API, which is documented here
[FCM HTTP v1 API Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages), to send a notification to multiple devices at once, but **without** using topics, or groups (let's say I want to send a notification to 10 random winners of some lottery). I know that in the previous version ([Legacy FCM HTTP Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)), this was possible by using the **registration_ids** parameter, but I don't see anything similar in the current API. Am I missing something? Is there a way to do this without using the legacy API?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue in my **php-laravel** app. And I have opened a bounty on this question. If you allow, I would like to add tags `php` and `laravel` to this question.

Comment: We didn't find any better solution than the answers of AL. and Jannie Theunissen below. Although I didn't mention it, my question was related to an Android app - where we eventually ended up creating some topics like LOGGED_IN | NOT_LOGGED_IN to differentiate these app states and 2 more for our users - based on their subscription type - in case we ever wanted to send push notifications to any of these groups specifically. Any other type of grouping would be too unnecessarily specific for our app, so the rest of the cases are resolved by simply calling the API for each user individually.

Comment: In our case, when an event (related to a single user) is occurred in our server, multiple devices of a single user should be notified (Usually 1-3 devices). [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices) Firebase provides an option for this, which involves file operations. But I think they provide this option for larger number of requests. Using this method for 1-3 devices would not be efficient.

Comment: @iamab.in There is a simpler solution if you are using FCM Legacy, see [Device Group Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-device-groups) (in the same docs you linked).

Comment: @AL. Currently i am using the FCM legacy method(registration_ids). But would like to migrate to HTTP V1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no other way to send to multiple tokens besides using topics for FCM v1.

In your mentioned use case, if I'm using v1, I would probably go at something like, after selecting the winning tokens, you subscribe them to a topic like `winningTokens<date_here>` then send the message.

Answer (score 2):

For other use cases, the best way to send to multiple devices via v1 API depends on your application. For example, the accepted answer would not be a good solution for a private chat application where another user can guess the topic name and evesdrop on the conversation by subscribing to the topic. In that scenario iterating over the device list and making multiple send calls to a single device would be better.